# Shifting camunda setup from java 7 to 8

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-8, camunda

I was earlier using java 1.7 but I installed 1.8, and now I get the following error while running the camunda

```
2016-05-10 11:10:29,652 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1) ScriptEngineManager providers.next(): javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory: Provider com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngineFactory not found
```

After a bit of research I found this [page](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/239467?start=0)
This page says that the module.xml file should include the rhinoscriptengine paths. What are those paths?
My module.xml looks like

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="sun.jdk">
<resources>
    <!-- currently jboss modules has not way of importing services from
    classes.jar so we duplicate them here -->
    <resource-root path="service-loader-resources"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <system export="true">
        <paths>
            <!-- todo create new nashorn/scripting module-->
            <path name="com/sun/script/javascript"/>
            <path name="sun/org/mozilla/javascript/internal"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/api/scripting"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/resources"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/codegen"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/codegen/types"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/ir"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/ir/annotations"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/ir/debug"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/ir/visitor"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/lookup"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/objects"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/objects/annotations"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/parser"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/arrays"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/linker"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/options"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/regexp"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/regexp/joni"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/resources"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/resources/fx"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/scripts"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/tools"/>
            <path name="jdk/nashorn/internal/tools/resources"/>
            <path name="jdk/internal/dynalink"/>
            <path name="jdk/internal/dynalink/beans"/>
            <path name="jdk/internal/dynalink/linker"/>
            <path name="jdk/internal/dynalink/support"/>
            <!-- END SCRIPTING-->
            <path name="com/sun/image/codec/jpeg"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/plugins/bmp"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/plugins/common"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/plugins/gif"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/plugins/jpeg"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/plugins/png"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/plugins/wbmp"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/spi"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/stream"/>
            <path name="com/sun/jndi/dns"/>
            <path name="com/sun/jndi/ldap"/>
            <path name="com/sun/jndi/url"/>
            <path name="com/sun/jndi/url/corbaname"/>
            <path name="com/sun/jndi/url/dns"/>
            <path name="com/sun/jndi/url/iiop"/>
            <path name="com/sun/jndi/url/iiopname"/>
            <path name="com/sun/jndi/url/ldap"/>
            <path name="com/sun/jndi/url/ldaps"/>
            <path name="com/sun/jndi/url/rmi"/>
            <path name="com/sun/media/sound"/>
            <path name="com/sun/crypto/provider"/>
            <path name="com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/security/transforms/implementations"/>
            <path name="com/sun/security/auth"/>
            <path name="com/sun/security/auth/login"/>
            <path name="com/sun/security/auth/module"/>
            <path name="com/sun/tools/internal/xjc"/>                
            <path name="sun/awt"/>
            <path name="sun/awt/color"/>
            <path name="sun/awt/datatransfer"/>
            <path name="sun/awt/dnd"/>
            <path name="sun/awt/event"/>
            <path name="sun/awt/geom"/>
            <path name="sun/awt/im"/>
            <path name="sun/awt/image"/>
            <path name="sun/awt/image/codec"/>
            <path name="sun/awt/motif"/>
            <path name="sun/awt/resources"/>
            <path name="sun/awt/shell"/>
            <path name="sun/awt/util"/>
            <path name="sun/awt/windows"/>
            <path name="sun/awt/X11"/>
            <path name="sun/dc"/>
            <path name="sun/print"/>
            <path name="sun/print/resources"/>
            <path name="sun/security/action"/>
            <path name="sun/security/pkcs"/>
            <path name="sun/security/x509"/>
            <path name="sun/jdbc/odbc"/>
            <path name="sun/jdbc/odbc/ee"/>
            <path name="sun/font"/>
            <path name="sun/misc"/>
            <path name="sun/io"/>
            <path name="sun/nio"/>
            <path name="sun/nio/ch"/>
            <path name="sun/nio/cs"/>
            <path name="sun/nio/cs/ext"/>
            <path name="sun/security"/>
            <path name="sun/security/util"/>
            <path name="sun/security/krb5"/>
            <path name="sun/util"/>
            <path name="sun/util/calendar"/>
            <path name="sun/util/locale"/>
            <path name="sun/util/resources"/>
            <path name="sun/security/pkcs11"/>
            <path name="sun/security/provider"/>
            <path name="sun/text"/>
            <path name="META-INF/services"/>
        </paths>
        <exports>
            <include-set>
                <path name="META-INF/services"/>
            </include-set>
        </exports>
    </system>
</dependencies>
```

Also I tried removing the rhino script from the ScriptEngineFactory file. That also gave me an error.

Does this mean that camunda is not compatible with java 8? And how can I fix this issue?

Softwares used:

- Camunda 7.4.0
- Wildfly 8.2.1

Comment: I am not using wildfly, but I can assure you that we are using camunda with Java8 withount any issues. So I believe the problem to be wildfly vs. Java8. Did you try the latest wildfly version?

Comment: The error you see is harmless, it is "logged" by ScriptEngine loading from ServiceLoader. Java8 comes with Nashorn instead of Rhino, but as WildFly 8 supports both Java 7 & 8 we have config for both present.
But that is just the error part, not sure about the Camuda itself.